# How to keep only the first paragraph of $product.description_short in a listing?

Tags: regex, prestashop, smarty, prestashop-1.6

I want to keep only the first paragraph of product description in categories.

Example: `<p>This is a pretty good description.</p><p>The rest of the description, even if it's cool to I don't want it.</p>`

To : `<p>This is a pretty good description.</p>`

This is the default code in product-list.tpl Prestashop (1.6):

```
<p class="product-desc" itemprop="description">
   {$product.description_short|strip_tags:'UTF-8'|truncate:360:'...'}
</p>
```

This is what I tried default code in product-list.tpl Prestashop (1.6):

```
<p class="product-desc" itemprop="description">
   {assign var $newdescription = $product.description_short|strip_tags:'UTF-8'|truncate:360:'...'}
   {preg_replace('(?<=<\/p>)\s+<p>.*','',$newdescription)}
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{$_shorten = explode('</p>', $product.description_short)}
// with valid html tags
{$_shorten.0|cat:'</p>'}
// or if you want to strip tags:
{$_shorten.0|strip_tags}
```

Comment: Hello @r_a_f
I tried the 2 ways above.
The last one is well displaying all <p> but I can't keep only the first one :/

Comment: so your html is probably more complex (empty spaces etc.) - try updated code (explode('</p>' ...)